# Vue.js, How to fill SweetAlert2 html form data from component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, sweetalert2

Firstly I am new to Vue and frontend.

I have a button that shows sweet alert in my ...

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-fill btn-wd" @click="showSwal('input-field')">Yeni</button>
```

and have this method;

```
showSwal(type) {
  if (type === 'input-field') {
      swal({
        title: 'Input something',
        html: '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<input id="input-field" type="text" class="form-control" />' +
        '</div>',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success btn-fill',
        cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger btn-fill',
        buttonsStyling: false
      }).then(function (result) {
        swal({
          type: 'success',
          html: 'You entered',
          confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success btn-fill',
          buttonsStyling: false
        })
      }).catch(swal.noop)
    }
}
```

instead of putting html data in this scope, I want to put my other template component NewMerchant.vue

I've tried

```
html: '<new-merchant></new-merchant>'
```

but it does not render it.

And I don't know if this can be done or not. Other frameworks like inspina mvc can achieve this from what I saw.

I'm using Vue Paper Dashboard Pro AdminTemplate

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking you can use

```
onOpen: () => {
   new Vue({
        el: ".swal2-content"
   });
},
```

Like so

```
swal({
    title: 'Input something',
    html: '<new-merchant></new-merchant>',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success btn-fill',
    cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger btn-fill',
    buttonsStyling: false
    onOpen: () => {
       new Vue({
            el: ".swal2-content"
       });
    },
  }).then(function (result) {
    swal({
      type: 'success',
      html: 'You entered',
      confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success btn-fill',
      buttonsStyling: false
    })
  }).catch(swal.noop)
```

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined`